TCPDF: Unable to Fill Forms in Adobe Acrobat with Password Protection Enabled
"I'm facing an issue with TCPDF where I'm using the SetProtection method to protect a PDF with an owner password. Here's the code snippet:
$pdf->SetProtection(
    array('print', 'modify', 'copy', 'annot-forms', 'fill-forms', 'extract', 'assemble', 'print-high'),
    $passw1, // Owner password
    $passw1, // User password
    2 // Encryption strength (2 = high)
);

However, after setting the password, I'm unable to fill forms and checkboxes in Adobe Acrobat when the password is provided. It seems like the protection settings are preventing form filling. Any suggestions on how to resolve this issue and allow form filling while still maintaining password protection?
Other tests: I can fill out the form using Edge, Chrome, and Firefox. Also, I tried a similar document encrypted by iPhone instead of TCPDF and was able to fill in Adobe.
Thank you for your assistance!"

You might check the settings in Acrobat (Reader) in the Security tab of the Document properties.

@K J : The leading PDF editors do honor the protection.
